# what wrong with my binding convert?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have radiobutton and I want to define binding between the radiobutton.IsChecked state and the visibility some stackpanel so I wrote this convert method:

```
 public class RadioBtnState2Visible : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        return ( bool )value == true ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        return ( Visibility )value == Visibility.Visible ? true : false;
    }
}
```

And I make the binding  -   The xaml:

```
 <local:PageEx.Resources>
       <local:RadioBtnState2Visible x:Key="Convert" />
 </local:PageEx.Resources>


 <RadioButton x:Name="MyRadioBtn1" GroupName="group1" />
 <RadioButton x:Name="MyRadioBtn2" GroupName="group1" />

  <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MyRadioBtn1, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource Convert}}" />
```

But nothing works!

The visibility state of the stackpanel is always Visible!

What I did wrong?

Comment: Output window doesn't help you? Have you tried to debug it? Breakpoints in converter?

Comment: i add breakpoint in the convert - its not stoping there.

Comment: which means converter is not getting fired

Comment: yes - there is no fired converter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got your code working with one minor change. I made the converter a page resource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:RadioBtnState2Visible x:Key="Convert" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I should also mention that I had to actually put something in the stackpanel as well to see the change as by default it collapses to nothing :) I assume you actually have content in your real stackpanel.

---

**Just to explain what is happening here. By adding "local:" to the resource declaration you are actually enclosing an instance of a Resource, and not changing the current resource. Referencing it by "Convert" does not work because it cannot find the resource where it expects to find it.**

Answer (score 1):

Is this Silverlight or WPF?  You might need to specify the Mode for the Binding.  Mode=OneWay should work.

Comment: Updated my answer to remove that part.  You can try specifying the Mode (see answer).

Comment: @Snowbear:  doh, you're right.  i misread it the first time.  :)  ill remove that from my answer

Answer (score 0):

In fact, RadioButon.IsChecked is not a `bool` but a `Nullable<bool>` [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

So, your code should be :

```
 public class RadioBtnState2Visible : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        return   (value == true) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; // the explicit check to true is needed because of  case value=null
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        return value == Visibility.Visible ; // yup, it's a boolean
    }
}
```

It should work better.

Comment: Its not work at all. still does not see any result of the stackpanel visibility.

Comment: That was my first thought, but it does cast from a bool? to a bool correctly. The converter resource was just declared wrong. He would have hit his breakpoint if the converter was used at all.